# What is the word for "intended for human use or consumption", as opposed to for an automated system?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word to describe "intended for human use or consumption", as in a document, or an image, or a sound?

For example:

- The text of a book is intended for a human reader
- An internet chat bot is intended for a human to interact with
- A flowchart or a graph is intended to illustrate something to a human
- The HTML code in a web document is intended for a computer to parse (and turn into a human-friendly visualization)
- The sounds that a fax machine sends over a telephone line are intended for a computer
- A bar code is intended for a computer
- The address on an envelope, or the contents of a bank check, were originally intended for human readers, although these are increasingly processed automatically by machines

What is the word that distinguishes between these two categories (for-humans vs for-machines)?

Comment: It is intended to be read or understood by a **machine**, which is not always a computer (e.g. phone tones and bar codes). It seems strange to say that something is intended for a human to read. A book was never read by a machine *historically*, and chatbots don't talk to each other (although that might happen).

Comment: I'll make a note that we do have the expression "natural language" to distinguish English, French, etc., from, say, programming languages or markup languages.

Answer (score 3):

Human-readable.

To [*read*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/read) is to

> to look at words or symbols and understand what they mean

in which sense no machine has ever read so much a jot or tittle yet, unless you are willing to be broad with your definition of "understand",

or

> to understand and give a particular meaning to written information, a statement, a situation, etc.:

That is, I mean to say, *reading* is a peculiarly human activity in the first place, and the distinction between human- and machine-"readable" data is one that has gotten a lot of attention in the last hundred years or so. Still, the only one-word answer that I know is hyphenated: "human-readable"! It is used mainly in the context of computer-related information, like [on softwareengineering.stackexchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/17121/what-does-human-readable-mean-is-it-a-misnomer) but it can also be used for legalese translated to layman's terms.

Eric S. Raymond's compilation at [catb.org](http://www.catb.org/~esr/jargon/html/S/source.html) says:

> source: n.
>       [very common] In reference to software, source is invariably shorthand for ‘source code’, the preferred human-readable and
>   human-modifiable form of the program. This is as opposed to object
>   code, the derived binary executable form of a program. This shorthand
>   readily takes derivative forms; one may speak of “the sources of a
>   system” or of “having source”.

There is also a verb for making some kind of otherwise obscure data more accessible to the human glance:

> prettyprint: /prit-ee-print/, v.
>       (alt.: pretty-print)
>       1. To generate ‘pretty’ human-readable output from a hairy internal representation; esp. used for the process of grinding (sense
>   1) program code, and most esp. for LISP code.
>       2. To format in some particularly slick and nontrivial way.

**Edit:**
Another option, that I just now found in an answer at this (very similar) ELU Post: [antonym for machine readable data](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/229823/antonym-for-machine-readable-data), is "un-structured data" (vs. "structured" or "formal".

Comment: The problem with "human-readable" is that some things which are incidentally readable by humans (like source code) are actually intended for consumption by machines (compilers, interpreters).

Comment: As in written-to-be-human-readable? That's a lot to ask of one word...;)

Comment: @AndreyMishchenko computer "source code" is intended to be read by both humans *and* machine. That is its purpose: an interface between the way people think and the way computers operate.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'll give it a go. What we're talking about here seems to be language of some kind presented in some way. Sow how about **human-friendly** as the modifier to characterize language "intended for human use or consumption"? Your examples:

> Text of a book -- **human-friendly**
>
> Internet chat bot -- **human-friendly**
>
> Flowchart or graph -- **human-friendly**
>
> HTML -- **not human-friendly** for most humans
>
> Sounds a fax machine sends over a telephone line -- **not human-friendly**
>
> Bar code -- **not human-friendly**
>
> The address on an envelope readable by a machine -- not completely sure about this one, but I suspect that the format of addresses readable by computers is, like bar codes, **not human-friendly**
>
> The contents of a bank check -- not completely sure about this one either, but the contents of a bank check readable by computers, e.g., account and routing numbers, appear-to contain characters that are **not human-friendly**

The flip side of **human-friendly** is **machine-friendly**.

> HTML -- **machine-friendly**
>
> Sounds a fax machine sends over a telephone line -- **machine-friendly**
>
> Bar code -- **machine-friendly**
>
> The address on an envelope readable by a machine -- **machine-friendly**
>
> The contents of a bank check readable by computers -- **machine-friendly**